# Flutter : when i try to run flutter app that i clone from github, but the build failed, could someone inform me how to solve it?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, build

```
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
error: warnings found and -Werror specified

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':connectivity:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you app/build.gradle file
under `android {` sections

```
lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
    warning("all")
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

This code will stop the issue for you and would stop getting those warnings like errors message.

Answer (score -1):

That error message means, your java code has warning. and since `-Werror` flag, it becomes an error.

The warning says, your java target version is too old.

Thus, you may upgrade that version. Or, remove `-Werror`.